# How can I quickly find the smallest integer satisfying a bitmask and greater than another integer?

Tags: algorithm, search, bit-manipulation

### TL;DR:

How can I quickly find the smallest integer that satisfies `int > floor && ((int ^ bits) & mask) == 0`, where `floor`, `bits` and `mask` are known? (Ideally a non-looping, non-branching solution, probably with some serious bit-twiddling involved.)

### Background

Suppose I have a list of key-values sorted by key, where each key is an integer. I want to quickly gather each value whose key has certain flags set or clear, i.e. matches the filter `(key & mask) == (bits & mask)` or equivalently `((key ^ bits) & mask) == 0`.

In a naïve implementation, I could iterate over every key-value and gather those matching the filter. However, if my matches are sparse, I'd like to take advantage of my list's sortedness to quickly find new matches.

So my current approach is an algorithm that switches back and forth between binary-searching and scanning the list, maintaining the smallest possible future key *based on the last key read in*. If a search for the key succeeds, it scans until the the read-in key no longer matches the filter. Either way, the search begins anew with a newly computed "smallest possible future key" based on the last key we read in (aka `floor`, which doesn't match the filter.)

My testing has shown the algorithm to be correct (thankfully), but I'm using a placeholder iterative method to compute the "next" key instead of a bit-twiddling method like I was hoping to have come up with... which brings us back to the *TL;DR!*

Comment: What language? Are the values signed or unsigned?

Comment: @Dai For this question let's suppose we're using C with 32-bit unsigned integers.

Comment: (I say "suppose" because I'm actually using Kotlin, but I don't want to bog things down with those specifics. I think any language with bit manipulation and bit-intrinsics should be able to benefit from the solution. The JVM has access to leading-zero and trailing-zero intrinsics, fwiw.)

Comment: From your background, can we assume that `floor` itself satisfies the bitmask?

Comment: @btilly Unfortunately we cannot - in my use case, the whole point is to take a non-satisfying key and output the next possible key that can. Relying on a satisfying key floor would entail significant drawbacks to the algorithm - searching on each possible key in the "space", one at a time, until entirely exhausted. This property allows us to "skip ahead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, though it does not quite meet the strictest version of your criteria. It's not too bad though, a few branches is all.

The condition `((key ^ bits) & mask) == 0` (henceforth "The Condition") requires some bits to take on particular values, I will call those bits the "fixed bits" and other bits the "non-fixed bits". WLOG I will assume that `(bits & mask) == bits`.

Consider `floor`. How would it have to change to fit The Condition? Some bits may have to be set to match the fixed bits, some bits may have to be reset to match the fixed bits. Sometimes no bits would have to be changed. Let's consider some different cases:

- `floor` already satisfies The Condition. But `floor` isn't larger than `floor`, so we have to increment it, but without violating The Condition. Incrementing a number of which some bits stay fixed has a known solution: `(floor | mask) + 1 & ~mask | bits`, which could be redundantly parenthesized to `(((floor | mask) + 1) & ~mask) | bits`
- The highest "wrong" bit in `floor`, at index `i`, needs to be set. In that case, setting that bit would enable the lower non-fixed bits to become zero without going below `floor`. So we reset all the bits below `i`, and then bitwise-OR with `bits` to fill in the fixed bits.
- The highest "wrong" bit in `floor`, at index `i`, needs to be reset. Resetting it would decrease the value below `floor`, so the non-fixed bits above `i` need to be incremented. We can use a variant of the trick seen in the first case, but instead of adding `1`, we add `1 << i`. Then again we reset all the bits below that and OR with `bits`.

The conditional addition of `1 << i` if bit `i` of `x` is set, could be implemented as adding `x & (1 << i)`.

There are different ways to actually implement that, for example (somewhat tested):

```
uint32_t next_above_with_pattern(uint32_t floor, uint32_t mask, uint32_t bits)
{
    uint32_t x = floor;
    if (((x ^ bits) & mask) == 0)
    {
        x = (x | mask) + 1 & ~mask | bits;
    }
    else
    {
        int highestIndexOfViolation = 31 - (int)_lzcnt_u32((x ^ bits) & mask);
        x = (x | mask) + (x & (1UL << highestIndexOfViolation)) & ~mask | bits;
        x &= ~((1UL << highestIndexOfViolation) - 1);
        x |= bits;
    }
    return x;
}
```

With some changes as suggested by Ben

```
uint32_t next_above_with_patternD(uint32_t floor, uint32_t mask, uint32_t bits)
{
    uint32_t x = floor;
    if (((x ^ bits) & mask) == 0)
    {
        x = (((x | mask) + 1) & ~mask) | bits;
    }
    else
    {
        uint32_t maskOfHighestViolation = 0x80000000U >> _lzcnt_u32((x ^ bits) & mask);
        x = (((x | mask) + (x & maskOfHighestViolation)) & ~mask) | bits;
        x &= ~(maskOfHighestViolation - 1);  // could be -maskOfHighestViolation 
        x |= bits;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: That expression in the first branch / first bullet badly needs some additional grouping parentheses.  Arithmetic and bitwise operations aren't related to each other, so don't rely on their relative precedence.

Comment: `(1UL << highestIndexOfViolation)` appears a bunch of times, maybe introduce a temp variable for it (`leftmostWrongBit`).  Besides if you're going to hardcode `31` you might as well just right-shift, ala `(0x80000000U >> _lzcnt((x ^ bits) & mask))`

Comment: I think you need to or with (bits & mask) not just with bits.

Comment: @maraca perhaps, but I did mention that I assume that `(bits & mask) == bits`. It doesn't change anything interesting, `bits` having bits set outside of the mask is a weird and useless case

Comment: Tested the solution in Kotlin and it passed everything I could throw at it. Thank you! I'm going to keep tinkering with it and profiling.

Your first case is actually what I had intuited and continued to test, but goes to show that intuition only goes so far. I feel like I was missing the vocabulary to reason about bits related to addition, and that really kept me from reasoning about the problem.

Maybe if I revisit my digital logic textbook I could learn something...

Comment: @PhilipGuin I also recommend The Art of Computer Programming volume 4 chapter 7.1.3 Bitwise tricks and techniques, which goes into such things and how to reason about them.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a bit swizzling operation, this would be really easy:

1. Starting with `floor`, swizzle away the bits controlled by mask leaving only the variable bits.  Let this be `v(floor)`
2. Compute `1+v(floor)`
3. For the results of both step 1 and 2, swizzle the mask-controlled bits back in.  Compare to `floor`, picking the lower feasible value.

However, bit interleaving ("swizzling") is not one of the fundamental operations on a CPU (With an FPGA it is trivial)

Comment: @harold: Hmmm.  Do you agree with my code producing `candidate1` though?

Comment: I agree that it will satisfy the pattern of locked bits, but since bits may be set by the OR with `bits` without lower bits being reset, even when `candidate1 > floor` that may not be the lowest possible value

Comment: Ahh, also a good point @harold

Comment: I tried implementing the bit swizzling approach based on PEXT and PDEP but again I ran into that same issue when `floor = 2, mask = 2, bits = 0` resulting in 1 (or, nothing? neither candidate is feasible) instead of 4, neither of the candidates is 4, they're 0 and 1, at least if I understood the approach correctly